# for each only running once

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

First let me explain. I have several addresses on the page that I put into an array. I then want to go over that array and replace each address with its longitude and latitude.

The problem is my attempt only runs one time.

```
$(function () {
 var addr = 0;
 var shops = [];
 var addressPoint;
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -97);
 var myOptions = {
     zoom: 8,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 window.onload = function () {
     var options = [];
     $('.address').each(function () {
         if (!$(this).is(":empty")) {
             options.push($(this).text());
             txt = $(this).text();
         } else {}
     });
     alert(options);
     $.each(options, function () {
         var addr = ("'" + this + "'");
         searchAddr(addr);
     });

     function searchAddr(addr) {
         $('#map_canvas').gmap({
             'callback': function () {
                 var self = this;
                 alert(addr);
                 self.search({
                     'address': addr
                 }, function (results, status) {
                     if (status === 'OK') {
                         addressPoint = results[0].geometry.location;
                         alert(addressPoint);
                         options = $.map(options, function () {
                             return results[0].geometry.location;
                         });
                         self.get('map').panTo(results[0].geometry.location);
                         alert(options);
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     }
 };
 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: try to replace the alert(options) for console.log(options) and tell what shows the console (firebug in firefox and dev tools in chrome)

Comment: `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=src:apiv3".
[
Q
, 
Q
Ua: 37.76549929999999
Va: -122.39669270000002
__proto__: Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
Ua: 37.76549929999999
Va: -122.39669270000002
__proto__: Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
, 
Q
]`then `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type 
e`

Comment: What does only run once?

Comment: `$.each(options, function () {
         var addr = ("'" + this + "'");
         searchAddr(addr);
     });` it will run the 'searchAddr' function once and it makes every item of the original array display the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use a network sniffer to confirm it is only firing once? Because it looks like you are replacing each value in the list with a single value in the `$.map` command. Perhaps if you put the address points in a different array it would help:

```
$(function () {
 var addr = 0;
 var shops = [];
 var addressPoint;
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(38, -97);
 var myOptions = {
     zoom: 8,
     center: latlng,
     mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };
 var points = [];
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
 window.onload = function () {
     var options = [];
     $('.address').each(function () {
         if (!$(this).is(":empty")) {
             options.push($(this).text());
             txt = $(this).text();
         } else {}
     });
     alert(options);
     $.each(options, function () {
         var addr = ("'" + this + "'");
         searchAddr(addr);
     });

function searchAddr(addr) {
         $('#map_canvas').gmap({
             'callback': function () {
                 var self = this;
                 alert(addr);
                 self.search({
                     'address': addr
                 }, function (results, status) {
                     if (status === 'OK') {
                         addressPoint = results[0].geometry.location;
                         alert(addressPoint);
                         points.push(addressPoint);
                         });
                         self.get('map').panTo(addressPoint);
                         alert(points);
                         return false;
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     }
};
 }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Just tried your code, and when it alerts the points array there is only one value. Also it is only alerted that one time, so it still seems to be running just once.

Comment: all I'm seeing in the console is `Resource interpreted as Image but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/gen_204?ev=api_viewport&cad=src:apiv3".
e`

Comment: it's strange that it's not breaking. But I managed to fix it, using code similar to yours. Thank you